# How to get Code Compare to open inside Visual Studio to display compare results?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, codecompare

I am running VS 2013 and Devart Code Compare 4.0.51 (free).

After changing some setting, whenever I do a compare from within Visual Studio a full Code Compare window is opened to display the differences between the two files, rather than displaying the differences within Visual Studio.

**How do I get it back to displaying inside Visual Studio?**

I have looked through the settings both in the separate Code Compare instance as well as in Visual Studio, but can't seem to find anything relevant. Google was decidedly unhelpful in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

For 4.0.77, in the standalone application in "Tools>Options..."

Then "Environment>General"

There is a tick box for "Use standalone application from the command line by default" (2nd option for me), you need to un-check that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AnkhSVN:

Tools > Options > Source Control > Subversion User Tools:

External Diff Tool:

"C:\Program Files\Devart\Code Compare\CodeCompare.exe" /SC=SVN /t1="$(BaseName)" /t2="$(MineName)" "$(Base)" "$(Mine)" **/environment=visualstudio**

External Merge Tool:

"C:\Program Files\Devart\Code Compare\CodeMerge.exe" /SC=SVN /REMOVEFILES /BF="$(Base)" /BT="$(BaseName)" /MF="$(Mine)" /MT="$(MineName)" /TF="$(Theirs)" /TT="$(TheirsName)" /RF="$(Merged)" /RT="$(MergedName)" **/environment=visualstudio**

If you're using another source code server or client just make sure to put it the last parameter shown above.

(Source: email from Devart support)

Comment: Reversely use /environment=standalone to force using the standalone app if you're stuck in VS integration (I add this because typing "Stop Code Compare Visual Studio integration" in a search engine may ironically give you this page).